# Delete confirmation using sweetalert?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm trying to create delete confirmation in my app using sweetalert, here is what I've done so far..

View :

```
<div class="box-button">
     {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'deleteedition', 'action' => ['EditionController@destroy', $edition->id]]) !!}
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
     {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', 'id'=>'deleteedition1']) !!}
     {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
            $("#deleteedition1").on("click", function () {
                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                        function () {
                            $(".deleteedition").submit();
                        });
            });
        </script>
```

The problem is when I click the delete button it will keep deleting the file even thought I haven't confirm it. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong ? Thanks for the help!

Full table view :

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-responsive" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="overflow: hidden;"></th>

                                    @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 'admin')
                                    <th style="width: 130px;"></th>
                                    @endif

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($edition_list as $edition): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="overflow: hidden;"><a href="{{ url('edition/' . $edition->id) }}">Volume {{ $edition->volume }}, Nomor {{ $edition->number }} ({{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->start)->format('F, Y') }})</a>
                                            @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->status == '1')
                                            @if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->between(Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->start), Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)))
                                            <p style="font-size: 10px; color: red;">Edisi aktif periode : {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->start)->format('j F Y') }} sampai {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($edition->limit)->format('j F Y') }}</p>
                                            @else
                                            <p></p>
                                            @endif
                                            @endif
                                        </td>

                                        @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 'admin')
                                        <td style="overflow: hidden; width: 210px;">
                                            <div class="box-button">
                                                {{ link_to('edition/' . $edition->id . '/edit', 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="box-button">
                                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'deleteedition', 'action' => ['EditionController@destroy', $edition->id]]) !!}
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                                                {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', 'id'=>'deleteedition1']) !!}
                                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        @endif
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are using a foreach($edition_list as $edition) loop and then hardcoding the id in `{!!Form::submit}}` as `id=deleteedition1` which would mean same id for all delete buttons in the table.

Instead you could try to generate the form ids dynamically and on submit button you can have the reference through data-file attribute like

```
<div class="box-button">
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'class' => "deleteedition edition", 'id'=>'edition-'.$edition->id, 'action' => ['EditionController@destroy', $edition->id]]) !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-edition-btn', 'data-file'=>"edition-".$edition->id]) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Then in your script

```
<script>
    $(".delete-edition-btn").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var file= '#'+this.attr('data-file'),
            formId='form'+file,
            parent=this.parents(formId);
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function () {
            $(parent).submit();
        });
    });
</script>  

Or 
//here you don't depend upon dynamic ids but use the jQuery closest()
<script>
    $(".delete-edition-btn").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function(){
            // Use closest() to find the correct form in the DOM
           $(this).closest("form.deleteedition").submit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) as:

```
<script>
    $("#deleteedition1").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function () {
            $(".deleteedition").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it worked but it will delete the whole file in the list, not just one file, the default alert using `return confirm()` worked fine and will only delete the selected list. :/

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's `preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent form from submitting like this:

```
$("#deleteedition1").on("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); <-------- here

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function () {
       // Use closest() to find the correct form in the DOM
       $(this).closest("form.deleteedition").submit();
    });
});
```

You can use jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the correct file from the HTML DOM.

> According to jQuery Docs: If this method is called, the default action
>   of the event will not be triggered

Hope this helps!

Comment: it worked but it will delete the whole file in the list, not just one file, the default alert using `return confirm()` worked fine and will only delete the selected list. :/

Comment: I didn't get you, where is the list of files?

Comment: what do you mean by "where" ? it's a data record in a table with delete button action in every single record. I can't explain it well since my English is not so good

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a look. Use `closest()`

Comment: tried your updated answer, but now it won't allow me to click the confirm button. but when I remove the confirmation it worked fine and will the delete the related record. I'm suspecting I messed up with the button view, I've updated my question with the full table view :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you handle submit event of all your delete form. And, if swal confirmed, form will submit

```
$('.deleteedition').on('submit',function(){
    return swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this lorem ipsum!", type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function () {
       // Use closest() to find the correct form in the DOM
       //$(this).closest("form.deleteedition").submit();
       return true;
    });
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).submit()` as you are handling the submit event on the form itself? Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: when you handle submit, you don't need to use $(this).submit() because it will trigger submit event, and you will have recursion. You should return true (submit) or false (do nothing)